# Testing in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I trying testing in my reactive form, but I have no idea how to make a mistake and not jasmine: "Can't read property 'controls' from undefined"
my form:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  dateYMD: new FormControl(new Date()),
  teste: [this.userService.User.teste, Validators.required],
  teste: [this.userService.User.teste],
  teste: [this.userService.User.profile.personal.teste, [Validators.required]],
  teste: [this.userService.User.profile.personal.teste, [Validators.required]],
  teste: [this.userService.User.profile.personal.teste, [Validators.required]],
  teste: [this.userService.User.profile.personal.teste, [Validators.required]],
  teste: [this.userService.User.profile.personal.teste, [Validators.required]],
})
```

My test:

```
it('test form',(done)=>{
let name = personalComponent.form.controls["teste"];
teste.setValue("lucas");
let email = personalComponent.form.controls["teste"];
teste.setValue("lucas@email.com");
let gender = personalComponent.form.controls["teste"];
teste.setValue(0);
let marital_status = personalComponent.form.controls["teste"];
teste.setValue(0);
let teste = personalComponent.form.controls["teste"];
teste.setValue("2021-08-10");
let teste = personalComponent.form.controls["teste"];
teste.setValue("99999999999");
let teste = personalComponent.form.controls["teste"];
teste.setValue("00088880088");
expect(personalComponent.form.valid).toBeTruthy();
done();
```

})
The name "teste" is provisional only for doubt

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate component in beforeEach

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PersonalComponent);
    personalComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
}
```

Comment: beforeEach( () => {
 
    personalComponent = new PersonalComponent(modalService,userService,fb,errorService,profileService,progressService,localeService)
  }); 
I instantiated that way

Comment: Try with [TestBed](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/angular-test-bed/)

Comment: Now error : R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BsModalService -> BsModalService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for BsModalService!

Comment: you need to configure the module first `TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declaration:[PersonalComponent], providers: [BsModalService]})`

Comment: How are you getting the dependencies in test? (BsModalService)

Comment: I imagine I'm doing it wrong, I'm just declaring no before

Comment: I recommend you to go through [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/overview/) before writing tests.